# Google Analytics in BigQuery: Getting userId who click specific event between certain date

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to know the UserID who click specific event in Google Analytics for android and ios device

```
WITH
  date_dict AS (
  SELECT
    DATE('2022-08-04') AS start_dt,
    DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 day) AS end_dt)
SELECT DISTINCT userId,
       DATE(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)),INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) AS date_key
FROM `ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'click bla bla'
      AND date_key between (select start_dt from date_dict) and (select end_dt from date_dict)
```

I don't know the query is right or not. The idea is i want to join this userid to another table. Any suggestion?

Comment: What happens when you run the query? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom report in Google Analytics interface with metrics, dimensions and filters you want to analyze and compare the results with BigQuery. If the number is the same the query is correct.